# Danish characters overlapping in sIFR

Tags: sifr

I have a problem with overlapping characters.

Using sifr r436. The font is Dax, and the result is shown below. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be a Flash issue rather than a sIFR issue.